# Probability of an event and Number of times an event can occur

Tags: probability

Lets say, the probability of Event-A occuring when I do Event-X, P(A) = a.
Does that mean if I do the Event-X 100 times, I will get 100*a time the event A?

Like,  the probability of getting a head when you flip a coin= 0.5
Does that mean when I flip coin for 100 times, I will get 50 times head (or close to 50)?

Comment: The short punchline is that, yes: $n$ repetitions of an experiment, each trial of which having probability $p$ of success, will have an expected value of $np$ total successes.

Comment: Thanks!.........